# firebase-client-android-1.1.1 license terms and android vs jvm usage

Tags: android, firebase

I have couple of questions. Can I use

firebase-client-android-1.1.1.jar or firebase-client-jvm-1.1.1.jar are under apache 2.0 license? or should I get prior approval to use firebase for commercial software?

I have written samples (plain java) using the firebase-client-android-1.1.1.jar. These samples run as is with firebase-client-jvm-1.1.1.jar? I dont have any andoid specific code in my samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase client libraries are subject to the Firebase Terms of Service, available at https://www.firebase.com/terms/terms-of-service.html. They do not use any off-the-shelf license.